# Bash script: Find a file inside specific folder in linux

Tags: linux, bash, script, find

I want to write a script to find all executable files under a specific directory which I want to pass in parameter. I am able to find all executable files using a predefined directory but I want to be able to just pass a directory name and the script finds the directory in the file system and find all executable under it.

Can I do this with find command?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `find` should be capable of that:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -perm /ugo=x
```

Comment: Hi cYrus, thanks for the quick response. The problem is I dont have the path, I need to find the path to the directory name passed in command line

Comment: Can you elaborate? According to what criteria you need to find the path from *another* path passed as an argument? Let's say the input path is `/foo/bar/` and then?